# What is the difference between 「結局【けっきょく】」and 「とうとう」?

Tags: words, adverbs, synonyms

According to the dictionary I use to study, both are adverbs and their definitions are so similar that I can't tell the difference:

> [結局【けっきょく】](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%B5%90%E5%B1%80): after all; in the end; ultimately; eventually
>
> [とうとう](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%88%B0%E9%A0%AD): finally; at last; ultimately; in the end

What is the difference between both words (e.g. meaning, nuance, level of formality, style of speech, *none at all*…) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「とうとう」implies a continual process that led to the outcome, whereas 「結局」doesn't.

For example, one can say 「結局力不足なのだ」but not「とうとう力不足なのだ」because 力不足 is not a state achieved via a continuous process. On the other hand, one can both say「とうとう力尽きた」and「結局力尽きた」which has roughly the same meaning, but the former draws a lot more attention to the continued struggle that led to the outcome.

Other examples:

> Natural:「結局牛肉は好まれない」
>   Unnatural:「とうとう牛肉は好まれない」

> 1st:「少しづつ侵食が進み、とうとう倒壊した」
>   2nd:「少しづつ侵食が進み、結局倒壊した」

Both have very similar meanings, but the 1st describes how the gradual process eventually led to the outcome. The 2nd describes what the ultimate outcome was.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it better now. Just for the sake of clarification, by "2nd sentence is unnatural" which one are you referring to?,「とうとう牛肉は好まれない」or「少しづつ侵食が進み、結局倒壊した」？

Comment: 「とうとう牛肉は好まれない」is unnatural.